# How to use a pig latin translator npm module inside my React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to write a React/Redux app to translate an English sentence into Pig Latin. I found that there are some already existing npm [modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/piglatin) for this purpose, hence thought of reusing them. I wrote a simple functional component for this translation as below.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React from 'react';
import piglatin from 'piglatin';

function convertToPigLatin(data){
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/piglatin
  // return pigLatin(data);
}

export default (props) => {
  console.log(props.data);
  console.log(piglatin('hello there'));  // Works fine
  console.log(piglatin(props.data));    // gives an ERROR
  return (
    <label>Hello !</label>
  )
}
```

Simply I just wanted to log the translated text into the console.But when I try that out it works for a hard coded text after changing it as per the answer below.

```
console.log(piglatin('hello there'));  // Works fine
```

But when I pass real data it fails giving me this ERROR.

```
console.log(piglatin(props.data));    // gives an ERROR

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null at piglatin
```

I think this error occurs because we are missing `''` around the text.Finally I was able to solve the issue by using the ES6 back-tick operator as below.

```
console.log(piglatin(`${props.data}`));    // This solved the issue
```

You may find my code [here](https://github.com/ravindraranwala/piglatinconverterapp/) in github. How can I sort this out. Any help is really appreciated.

Later, I found that there's another [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pig-latin-converter) for the same purpose which is also a cool one. Both gives you identical results hence you may use either of them. There's a slight difference in code and I have posted it below.

```
import pigLatin from 'piglatin';

export const PIG_LATIN = 'PIG_LATIN';

export function pigLatinConvert(input){
  console.log(input);
  const output = pigLatin(`${input.inputtext}`);
  console.log(output);
  return {
    type: PIG_LATIN,
    payload: output
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that module's docs is looks like it should be

```
console.log(piglatin(props.data));
```

NOT

```
console.log(piglatin.piglatin(props.data));
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. Thanks for pointing that out. But I have another problem now and I have updated question. Could you please take a look.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using the back-tick `` operator in ES6. Thanks.